# How to populate value in one column from another column based on vale in other column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with Mnth_id and four financial quarter columns, i want to populate value in new column based on Mnth_id. Like if Mnth_id is 4(April), set new = Q1_A...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Mnth_id':[6, 3, 7, 8], 'Q1_A' : [1,2,3,4], 'Q2_A' : [2,3,4,5], 'Q3_A' : [3,4,5,6], 'Q4_A' : [2,3,4,5], 'new' :0})



    Name    Mnth_id Q1_A    Q2_A    Q3_A    Q4_A    new
0   Tom      6       1       2       3       2       0
1   nick     3       2       3       4       3       0
2   krish    7       3       4       5       4       0
3   jack     8       4       5       6       5       0
```

Here is the mapping:

```
month2quarter = { 4:'Q1', 5:'Q1', 6:'Q1', 7:'Q2', 8:'Q2', 9:'Q2', 10:'Q3', 11:'Q3', 12:'Q3', 1:'Q4', 2:'Q4', 3:'Q4' }
```

How can I populate values in new from specific columns based on month id?

Here is my expected output.

[image]

Comment: @ManojKhatua, looks like you ``new`` column data is wrong eg: Month_id is 6 which lies in ``Q3`` & new value shouldn't be ``3`` ??

Comment: @Sushanth according to the map, 4, 5, 6 are Q1

Comment: Actually this is financial year quarter which starts from April. So June comes under Q1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `mapping` dictionary from the mappings `month2quarter` which is used to map the values in column `Mnth_id` to corresponding quarter column, then use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the column `Mnth_id` with this `mapping` dictionary next use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to lookup the values in dataframe based on this mapped column:

```
mapping = {k: v + '_A' for k, v in month2quarter.items()}
df['new'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Mnth_id'].map(mapping))
```

Result:

```
    Name  Mnth_id  Q1_A  Q2_A  Q3_A  Q4_A  new
0    Tom        6     1     2     3     2    1
1   nick        3     2     3     4     3    3
2  krish        7     3     4     5     4    4
3   jack        8     4     5     6     5    5
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.map` and `np.where()`:

input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Mnth_id':[6, 3, 7, 8], 'Q1_A' : [1,2,3,4], 'Q2_A' : [2,3,4,5], 'Q3_A' : [3,4,5,6], 'Q4_A' : [2,3,4,5], 'new' :0})
month2quarter = {4:'Q1', 5:'Q1', 6:'Q1', 7:'Q2', 8:'Q2', 9:'Q2', 10:'Q3', 11:'Q3', 12:'Q3', 1:'Q4', 2:'Q4', 3:'Q4'}
```

code:

```
df['new'] = df['Mnth_id'].map(month2quarter)
df['new'] = np.where((df['new'] == 'Q1'), df['Q1_A'], df['new'])
df['new'] = np.where((df['new'] == 'Q2'), df['Q2_A'], df['new'])
df['new'] = np.where((df['new'] == 'Q3'), df['Q3_A'], df['new'])
df['new'] = np.where((df['new'] == 'Q4'), df['Q4_A'], df['new'])
df
```

output:

```
    Name    Mnth_id Q1_A    Q2_A    Q3_A    Q4_A    new
0   Tom     6       1       2       3       2       1
1   nick    3       2       3       4       3       3
2   krish   7       3       4       5       4       4
3   jack    8       4       5       6       5       5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David. This is working as expected. Personally i find the one Shubham suggested is bit more efficient.